# Zigzag footer change triangle color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, border, zigzag

I have a footer and im trying to do it with a zigzag border, it working properly but i want to change the color of the triangle to this color #67BA4D, how can i do that? 
here is my code:

```css
.BottomFooter {
position: relative;
    background-color: #67BA4D;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.BottomFooter:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 4px;
  /* red up pointing triangle */
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%228px%22%20height%3D%224px%22%3E%3Cpolygon%20points%3D%220%2C4%204%2C0%208%2C4%22%20fill%3D%22%23CC0000%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div class="BottomFooter">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                    <p> © 2017</p> <a href="#"></a> </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
                        <li><a href="#">privacy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">call us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: in u background-image: url take sub string `fill%3D%22%23CC0000`, `#cc0000` is a color. change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the data:image to:

```
  data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%228px%22%20height%3D%224px%22%3E%3Cpolygon%20points%3D%220%2C4%204%2C0%208%2C4%22%20fill%3D%22%2367BA4D%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E
```

The color code is at the end, after the "fill" argument.

```
data:image/svg xml,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8px" height="4px"><polygon points="0,4 4,0 8,4" fill="#67BA4D"/></svg>
```